# Mosquitto - Can't modify code in client/lib folders

Tags: c, mosquitto

I'm writing an extension to mosquitto, however I'm having the issue that only changes that I make in the src folder are actually reflected in the final mosquitto server and mosquitto_pub/mosquitto_sub clients. I originally set it up with CMake and compiled all of that, and now to rebuild the clients/server I run `make clean` and then `make` in the src and client folders. They compile fine and new clients are built, however no changes I made in the c files in the client/lib folders are actually in the compiled programs. Anyone know what is going on? Am I misunderstanding something about how to compile it or how it runs?

eg. I modified _mosquitto_handle_connack() in lib/read_handle_client.c to print a different message at line 32 (`_mosquitto_log_printf(mosq, MOSQ_LOG_DEBUG, "Client %s received CONNACK", mosq->id);`) however no matter what I change the text to it still displays the original text. I even modified _mosquitto_packet_handle() in lib/read_handle.c so that when it receives a CONNACK it doesn't do anything, but when I compile and re-run it still handles the CONNACK like in the standard mosquitto.

Edit: I've done a little bit more testing of the issue and I've found something weird. If I delete an entire method in one of the files, compilation will fail because the method doesn't exist. If I just delete everything inside the method, compilation will succeed and the program will act as if everything I've just deleted is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the problem is simple, I was running the clients without a ./ in front of them, so it was running the mosquitto clients I had installed (and completely forgotten about) 8 months earlier rather than the clients in the folder I was in.